# How do I make gcloud select the right project?

Tags: project, gcloud

I am using gcloud to realize speech2text. I had to reset my server and now have trouble getting gcloud recognize the right project.

transscript=$(curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth print-access-token) https://speech.googleapis.com/v1/speech:recognize -d @$mailpath/sync_request.json)

results in

"code": 403,
    "message": "Cloud Speech-to-Text API has not been used in project 32555940559 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/speech.googleapis.com/overview?project= then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.",

I have no clue where the wrong project number comes from.

I have tried gcloud config configurations list and the correct project is shown.
I have completely deinstalled the sdk.
I have assigned GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable

all without success.

expected result is assigned correct project

Answer (score 1):

as the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/print-access-token) reads:

> gcloud auth application-default print-access-token generates and prints an access token for the current Application Default Credential (ADC). The ADC can be specified either by setting the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable to the path of a service account key file (JSON) or using [gcloud auth application-default login](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/auth/application-default/login).

Answer (score 1):

You are using the undocumented (and un-recommended) `gcloud auth print-access-token`. This will use the default SDK client ID (which I'm guessing is in project `32555940559`), and the Speech API is not enabled in that project.

As Martin suggested, instead of using `gcloud auth print-access-token` you should use `gcloud auth application-default print-access-token`.

You can check if I'm right regarding the client ID by running `grep -r 'CLOUDSDK_CLIENT_ID =' $(dirname $(which gcloud))/../` (I just checked and, indeed, that project ID is the project for the default client ID).